# Redisplay text from a text file after being copied

Tags: javascript, php, html

So I have a textarea that grabs the text from a `.txt` file and a button that can copy this text.

I am having problems because I would like to replace the textarea value to `"... Copied to Clipboard"` for a quick second, then change it back to the text from the `.txt` file.

Here is the code in the header:

```
<?php 
$pfile = "proxies.txt";
$count = count(file($pfile));  

$proxyfile = fopen($pfile, "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
$proxyread = fread($proxyfile,filesize($pfile));
fclose($proxyfile);

$datefile = fopen("date.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
$dateread = fread($datefile,filesize("date.txt")); 
fclose($datefile);
?>
```

And here is the script with the problem:

```
<script>
function copyProxies() {

    var copyText = document.getElementById("proxies");
    copyText.select();
    copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999999)
    document.execCommand("copy");

    copyText.value = "[<?php echo $count ?>] Proxies Copied to Clipboard!";
    copyText.select();
    copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999999)

    setTimeout(function() {
        copyText.value = "<?php echo $proxyread ?>";
        copyText.select();
        copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999999)
    }, 750);

}
</script>
```

It all comes down to this one line not working:

```
copyText.value = "<?php echo $proxyread ?>";
```

If I change `copyText.value = "<?php echo $proxyread?>";` to -> `copyText.value = "test12345";` it works perfectly fine.

When I use the `echo $proxyread` in-between `<textarea></textarea>` it also works perfectly fine.
But when i am trying to use `copyText.value = "<?php echo $proxyread?>";` it doesn't work...at all...

Can someone tell me why I cannot re-display the text(proxies) onto the textarea after it has been copied? Would appreciate the help, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I figured out how to fix my problem not too long after posting this. I will show what I did in case others are having the same problem :)

I had an idea to save the text in the textarea before I changed it so I can just re-display the saved text instead of the `.txt` file text. (if that makes sense lol)

So after I declared `var copyText` I made another variable called `spt` (save proxy text) right underneath it and set it to grab the value of the textarea like so:

```
var spt = document.getElementById('proxies').value;
```

Then instead of doing all that extra `"<?php echo $proxyread ?>"` I just changed it to spt like so:

```
copyText.value = spt;
```

---

The fixed script:

```
<script>
function copyProxies() {

    var copyText = document.getElementById("proxies");

    /* Fix 1/2 */
    var spt = document.getElementById('proxies').value;

    copyText.select();
    copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999999)
    document.execCommand("copy");

    copyText.value = "[<?php echo $count ?>] Proxies Copied to Clipboard!";
    copyText.select();
    copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999999)

    setTimeout(function() {

        /* Fix 2/2 */
        copyText.value = spt;

        copyText.select();
        copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999999)
    }, 750);

}
</script>
```